# Android app can't connect to external apache mysql server

Tags: java, android, mysql, ubuntu

So I have an app that has a registration function, when the user clicks register the program should connect to an Apache MySQL server and insert the data into the phpMyadmin database however I get the error stated below.

**logcat:**

```
2020-04-04 21:43:52.035 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3736 bytes, containing 1 windows, 16 views
2020-04-04 21:44:17.157 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3736 bytes, containing 1 windows, 16 views
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:177)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:552)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1180)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBody(HurlStack.java:259)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:247)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:219)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:97)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:131)
2020-04-04 21:44:17.407 28854-28854/com.example.blooddonorsystem W/System.err:  ... 2 more
```

**Here's the code to connect to the server:**

```
//taken out the real url for obvious reasons
static String URL_REGIST = "http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx/android/register.php";



@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(!validate()) return;
    Register();
}

private void Register()
{
    //make button invisible and make loading widget visible
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    registerButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //get inputs and convert to strings
    final String name = this.nameInput.getText().toString().trim();
    final String emailAddress = this.emailAddressInput.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = this.passwordInput.getText().toString().trim();
   // final String confirmPassword = this.confirmPasswordInput.getText().toString().trim();
    final String postalAddress = this.addressInput.getText().toString().trim();
    final String phoneNumber = this.nameInput.getText().toString().trim();
   // final int phoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(this.nameInput.getText().toString().trim());
    final String bloodType = bloodTypeInput.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

    //start sending data to the database
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_REGIST,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        if(success.equals("1"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Error! Error inserting values to db" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        registerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Error! error connecting to db " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    registerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name",name);
            params.put("emailAddress",emailAddress);
            params.put("password",password);
            params.put("postalAddress",postalAddress);
            params.put("phoneNumber",phoneNumber);
            params.put("bloodType",bloodType);

            return params;
        }
    };
```

I've already added  to my AndroidManifest file.

I'm using a digital ocean ubuntu droplet to host the server, are there any settings I need to change on their other than allowing access through the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have added internet permissions in your manifest . if not please add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**If you are running app in emulator please uninstall and reinstall the application.**

Please check if this works for you.

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't work for me and I'm using my actual phone to test not an emulator but I did try with an emulator and it didn't work either

Comment: any other ideas?